# File already exist using system.io.file.copy

Tags: asp.net, file, copy

I'm using System.IO.File.Copy to copy files from serverA to serverB.  This works fine accept when the file exsist  I get an error "File already exist".  I tried trapping it using if file.exsist and nothing.

here is my code.

```
'Save files to disk
 FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("../pdf/audits/" & FileName))
 'Local Server
 Dim localPath As String = "\\server01\folder1$\pdf\audits\"
 'Remote Server
 Dim remotePath As String = "\\server02\folder2$\pdf\audits\"
 System.IO.File.Copy(localPath + FileName, remotePath + FileName)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx

Comment: I'm sorry the error was in my subject line "File already exist"

Answer (score 5):

If you just modify your copy operation like this, it should work. The last parameter will overwrite the file.

```
System.IO.File.Copy(localPath + FileName, remotePath + FileName, True);
```

Comment: Now i'm getting a different error "Access to the path denided". Which is not true if I delete the file it allows me to write to the path again.  If I take away the parameter True, I get the other error "File already exist".  There's got to be a way to get around it.

Comment: Try with a 'Full control' permission on the destination folder. This could also be some impersonation issue.

Comment: My server admin says that Full control is already on this folder.  He said it may be a HIPS issue on this particular server.  He is checking it out now.

Answer (score 2):

If you have large files, you are not going to want to overwrite them everytime. Try fixing your check to see if the file exist. Something like this (C#):

```
var localPath = @"C:\";
var remotePath = @"\\server\folder\";
var fileName = "test.txt";

if (!new System.IO.FileInfo(remotePath + fileName).Exists)
{
    System.IO.File.Copy(localPath + fileName, remotePath + fileName);
}
```

Comment: I did this one alreay, file is there plus I can see it as it copies, i have explorer open on the remote server as I'm testing.

Comment: It is working now, I'm using your code to check mine didn't work.                                                             If Not New System.IO.FileInfo(remotePath + FileName).Exists Then
                File.Copy(localPath + FileName, remotePath + FileName, overwrite)
            End If

Comment: I'm trying to use the File.Delete and it is not working.  Here is my code. Dim filePath As String = "\\server02\file$\rss\alert-special-reports2.xml" If Not New System.IO.FileInfo(filePath).Exists Then System.IO.File.Delete(filePath) End If .. Can you tell what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are checking to see if the file is NOT there, then you are trying to delete it. You can't delete a file that is not there, you will get an access denied error.

Answer (score 1):

There's a third parameter to overwrite if it already exists

```
System.IO.File.Copy(fileName, destName, overwrite);
```

Comment: As stated above when I use this parameter I get another error "Access to the path denided". Which is not true if I delete the file it allows me to write to the path again.

Comment: May be the user running the app pool does not have the required permission for this folder. Check your iss settings to see which user runs your app pool and check if it as permission to this folder.

Answer (score -1):

```
     I got it working with help from RLG.  

       'Save files to disk
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("../pdf/audits" & FileName))
        'SIGAR Public CMS
        Dim localPath As String = "\\hqdadev01\sigar_cms$\pdf\audits\"
        'SIGAR Dev
        Dim remotePath As String = "\\hqdadev02\sigar_public$\pdf\audits\"
```

Added this to check.

```
    If Not New System.IO.FileInfo(remotePath + FileName).Exists Then
        File.Copy(localPath + FileName, remotePath + FileName, overwrite)
    End If
```